# form action is not working when i come online

Tags: php, html, forms

i m using 000webhost.com for testing my website...
when i was using localhost the form was working properly..
[link to the testing website](http://natwet.hostei.com/Elunika/#)

the errors which it shows are jquery ajax based...
i don't think there is any problem in ajax, i think the form is not calling action

form...

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="login">
    <input id="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="em" />
    <input id="email" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="pwd"/>
    <div class="txt1"><input type="checkbox" name="check" />Keep me logged in |<a href="#"> Forgot Password ?</a></div>
    <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Login" name="log" />
    </form>
```

login.php page..

```
<?php
session_start();
include "incfiles/connection.php";
$user_login=$_POST['em'];
$password_login=$_POST['pwd'];
$password_login = md5($password_login);

if(empty($user_login) || empty($password_login))
{
die (retmsg(0,"Please fill Email and Password"));
}

$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from registration where email='$user_login' and password='$password_login'");
$read = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if(!$read)
{
    die (retmsg(0,"Incorrect Email or Password"));
}
else
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
    }
     $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
     $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
     $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
     if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"]) && isset($_SESSION["password_login"]))
     {echo retmsg(1,"profile.php?id=$id");}
 }

 function retmsg($status,$txt)
 {
return json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'txt' => $txt));
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It seems that the response is not JSON: "<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect() [<a href='function.mysqli-connect'>function.mysqli-connect</a>]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)...

Comment: your response says you mysql localhost permission denied, check your credentials

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. SQL injection is [very easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868). Use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead of concatenating variables into SQL.

Comment: thank you friends... i got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your site. The response from your server includes

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Check the database login credentials you are using, and ensure that you *are* using a password to log in to the database.

Comment: This. Check 'incfiles/connection.php' to see the credentials contained in the $con = new mysqli() string.